# actionscript 3 load xml not loading some tags

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm trying to load some XML into flash to populate some dynamic text fields. The problem I have is that some of the xml tags seem to be ignored by flash.

Here's the XML I'm loading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><xml>
  <node>
    <nid>2</nid>
    <name>Antonia O&#039;Neill</name>
    <jobtitle>Director</jobtitle>
    <photo>http://202.58.37.93/dev.mapandpage.com.au/backend/sites/default/files/MAP-holder.jpg</photo>
    <bio>&lt;p&gt;Antonia formed Map and Page in 2007 as an independent subsidiary of Macquarie Radio Network. In her role as Director she oversees corporate affairs and community relations for Macquarie Radio Network (2GB + 2CH), the Australian Jockey Club, John Singleton, Harvey Norman, Magic Millions, National Rugby League, and Maserati.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt; Her expertise in the full spectrum of communications; both corporate and consumer has seen the rapid growth of client base and team at Map and Page.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; Antonia has more than a decade&amp;rsquo;s experience in the free-to-air, commercial television industry having worked across a range of business units for the Seven Network (TV) including production, sport, publicity, events and sponsorship from 1995-2003.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; Antonia managed event marketing and client relations across four Olympic Games, Rugby World Cups, Commonwealth Games and Melbourne Cup Carnivals reporting directly to the CEO.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; In 2003, Antonia co-founded Launch Group a full service communications agency and in 2007 founded Map and Page in partnership with MRN...&lt;/p&gt;</bio>

  </node>
  <node>
    <nid>3</nid>
    <name>Julia Everingham</name>
    <jobtitle>Group Account Director</jobtitle>
    <photo>http://202.58.37.93/dev.mapandpage.com.au/backend/sites/default/files/MAP-holder_0.jpg</photo>
    <bio>&lt;p&gt;In her role as Group Account Director, Julia specialises in the development of strategic public relations campaigns working across a range of clients including the Australian Jockey Club (AJC), Coca-Cola Amatil, Bluetongue, Maserati, Percy Marks, Surf Life Saving Australia and Diamond Guild of Australia.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt; Julia brings more than fifteen years of public relations experience to MAP having previously established and run the highly successful Oxygen Marketing Communication. Her experience includes developing, implementing and managing communication programs for major brands and events.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; Her marketing communications expertise spans a broad array of industry groups including consumer, sport, telecommunications and media. Julia&amp;rsquo;s experience includes communication specialty areas of publicity and promotion, sports and event public relations, consumer marketing and luxury goods promotion.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; Julia has worked on both client and agency side of the business. She provides clients with highly experienced communication counsel with strong expertise in media management and leveraging, with an extensive media network.&lt;/p&gt;</bio>
  </node>

</xml>
```

Here's the actionscript:

```
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
//ignore white space
xmlData.ignoreWhite=true;

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
var theURL:String = ("http://202.58.37.93/dev.mapandpage.com.au/backend/?q=xml/team2&cachebuster=" + new Date().getTime());
trace(theURL);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(theURL));

function LoadXML(e:Event):void {

xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
ParseTeam2(xmlData);

}
function ParseTeam2(bookInput:XML):void  {

trace("XML Output");
trace("------------------------");
trace(bookInput);
}
```

Flash ignores the `<jobtitle>` and `<photo>` tags.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference, but how about `bookInput.toXMLString()`? Also, this may not be the issue, but according to xml specification, you cannot use the word `xml` (with any case combination - basically `/xml/i`) as an xml tag name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your xml file exactly and it works for me as expected. I can only suggest you check you are saving in UTF-8 and using Unix line-endings.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class XMLTest extends Sprite
{
    public function XMLTest()
    {
        var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
        var theURL:String = ("XMLTest.xml");
        xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(theURL));
    }

    private function loadXML(event:Event):void
    {
        var xmlData:XML = new XML(URLLoader(event.target).data);

        // all of these trace the expected values:
        trace(xmlData);
        trace(xmlData..jobtitle);
        trace(xmlData..photo);
    }
}
}
```

with xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><xml>
  <node>
    <nid>2</nid>
    <name>Antonia O&#039;Neill</name>
    <jobtitle>Director</jobtitle>
    <photo>http://202.58.37.93/dev.mapandpage.com.au/backend/sites/default/files/MAP-holder.jpg</photo>
    <bio>&lt;p&gt;Antonia formed Map and Page in 2007 as an independent subsidiary of Macquarie Radio Network. In her role as Director she oversees corporate affairs and community relations for Macquarie Radio Network (2GB + 2CH), the Australian Jockey Club, John Singleton, Harvey Norman, Magic Millions, National Rugby League, and Maserati.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt; Her expertise in the full spectrum of communications; both corporate and consumer has seen the rapid growth of client base and team at Map and Page.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; Antonia has more than a decade&amp;rsquo;s experience in the free-to-air, commercial television industry having worked across a range of business units for the Seven Network (TV) including production, sport, publicity, events and sponsorship from 1995-2003.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; Antonia managed event marketing and client relations across four Olympic Games, Rugby World Cups, Commonwealth Games and Melbourne Cup Carnivals reporting directly to the CEO.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; In 2003, Antonia co-founded Launch Group a full service communications agency and in 2007 founded Map and Page in partnership with MRN...&lt;/p&gt;</bio>

  </node>
  <node>
    <nid>3</nid>
    <name>Julia Everingham</name>
    <jobtitle>Group Account Director</jobtitle>
    <photo>http://202.58.37.93/dev.mapandpage.com.au/backend/sites/default/files/MAP-holder_0.jpg</photo>
    <bio>&lt;p&gt;In her role as Group Account Director, Julia specialises in the development of strategic public relations campaigns working across a range of clients including the Australian Jockey Club (AJC), Coca-Cola Amatil, Bluetongue, Maserati, Percy Marks, Surf Life Saving Australia and Diamond Guild of Australia.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt; Julia brings more than fifteen years of public relations experience to MAP having previously established and run the highly successful Oxygen Marketing Communication. Her experience includes developing, implementing and managing communication programs for major brands and events.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; Her marketing communications expertise spans a broad array of industry groups including consumer, sport, telecommunications and media. Julia&amp;rsquo;s experience includes communication specialty areas of publicity and promotion, sports and event public relations, consumer marketing and luxury goods promotion.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; Julia has worked on both client and agency side of the business. She provides clients with highly experienced communication counsel with strong expertise in media management and leveraging, with an extensive media network.&lt;/p&gt;</bio>
  </node>

</xml>
```

Comment: Thanks James. It turned out to be a server side issue. I would've been chasing my tail for hours without your help.